# Propagation of sound waves and monopole

Tags: waves, acoustics, wavelength

While it is understood that in order for the acoustic waves to reach far field the wavelength should be less than the characteristic length of the source, I am not able to physically understand how?

Why should sound source of large wavelength should be large? Why can't smaller objects set a large wavelength or does large wavelength mean setting a large number of particles in vibration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a small diapragm moving slowly then the air will just flow around it and you won't get any appreciable pressure rise in front of the diaphragm. That means there won't be any longitudinal pressure waves (i.e. sound waves) generated normal to the diaphragm surface.

[image: Diaphragm]

If you now make the diaphragm larger the air has farther to move to get to the edge and flow round it, and as a result you do get a significant amount of the energy radiated as a sound wave normal to the surface.

It is possible to generate low frequency waves from a small diaphragm, but you need some form of impedance matching. Typically this is done with a cone, and the resulting speaker is known as a [horn speaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_loudspeaker).

[image: Horn speaker]

(picture from the Wikipedia article)